# apt-get install -g grunt grunt-cli missing modules

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm using a Ubuntu 14.04 server and am trying to install grunt & grunt-cli with this command:

```
npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
```

Everything looks fine, no errors are recieved. But when I run the standard grunt command, I recieve this error:

```
module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'eventemitter2'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/unsplit/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/event.js:13:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at gRequire (/var/www/html/unsplit/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:23:24)
at Object.<anonymous>  (/var/www/html/unsplit/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:35:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3`
```

What would be causing this to happen?

Comment: try to run npm update first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some strange reason, once I ran:

`npm remove -g grunt grunt-cli`

And re-ran:

`npm install -g grunt grunt-cli`

And everything was working!